# Bakery algorithm: How does it work with single-writer safe registers?

Tags: concurrency, synchronization

I'm trying to understand the bakery algorithm and read that the Bakery algorithm uses single-writer safe registers. But I am not able to understand the correctness of bakery algorithm with safe registers. Since safe register may return any value that the register may hold If a read does overlap any writes.

```
 choosing[i] = true; 
 number[i] = max(number[0], number[1], …, number [n – 1])+1; 
 choosing[i] = false; 
 for (j = 0; j < n; j++) { 
     while (choosing[j]);
     while ((number[j]!= 0) && (number[j],j)<(number[i],i))); 
 } 
 critical section 
 number[i] = 0; 
 remainder section
```

It is possible to execute `(number[j],j)<(number[i],i)` while thread `j` trying to update to `number[j]`. If the `number[j]` is a safe register and it returns a value less than `number[i]` (*safe register may return any value that the register may hold If a read does overlap any writes*) then we will wrongly wait on the while check.

Is my observation correct or could you please help me to understand why safe register does not matter?